# Zend Framework 2 - Cookie Concept

Tags: zend-framework2

I have surfed a lot. I would like to assign and retrieve a value using a COOKIE. How can i do in ZF2? I saw a lot of examples for assigning value in cookie. Please explain that how to retrieve a value from cookie.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A cookie in HTTP (see [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) simply something stored in the request and send every time a request is made. A response *can* add other parameters to be stored additionally to the already existing cookies.

So the cookie *retrieval* is done via the `Request`, to *update* a cookie you use the `Response`. According to RFC 2109 you use respectively the `Cookie` header and the `Set-Cookie` header. You can thus directly access these headers via

```
$this->getRequest()->getHeaders()->get('Cookie')->foo = 'bar';
```

Or set cookies via:

```
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->get('Set-Cookie')->foo = 'bar';
```

Things are made a little bit easier though because there is a proxy at the request and response to directly access the cookie:

```
public function fooAction()
{
  $param = $this->getRequest()->getCookie()->bar;

  $this->getResponse()->getCookie()->baz = 'bat';
}
```

Keep in mind the `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers implement the `ArrayObject` object. To check whether a cookie is present in the request, you can thus use `offsetExists`:

```
if ($cookie->offsetExists('foo')) {
    $param = $cookie->offsetGet('foo');
}
```

/update:

If you want to modify properties of the cookie, you are also here modifying the `Set-Cookie` header. Take a look [at the class on Github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Header/SetCookie.php) for all the methods available.

A slight summary:

```
$cookie = $this->getResponse()->getCookie();
$cookie->foo = 'bar';
$cookie->baz = 'bat';

$this->setDomain('www.example.com');
$this->setExpires(time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, how can i set cookie expiry time, domain name and cookie path.

Comment: You can create a new SetCookie header for that and assign it to the response object's headers list. Example: `$cookie = new SetCookie($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly, $maxAge, $version); $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);`.

Comment: @2plus see my edit, I linked to the SetCookie class where all modifiers are available. A short example of a few setters is added as well to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The cookie access via `$this->getResponse()->getCookie()` works but is long-winded and tiresome. So what I did, I extended Response and Request classes. Here what it looks like:

```
'service_manager' => array (
    'factories' => array (
        'Request' => 'Application\Mvc\Request\Factory',
        'Response' => 'Application\Mvc\Response\Factory',
    )
);
```

module/Application/src/Application/Mvc/Request/Factory.php

```
namespace Application\Mvc\Request;

use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest;
use Zend\Console\Console;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (Console::isConsole ())
        {
            return new ConsoleRequest ();
        }

        return new HttpRequest ();
    }
}
```

module/Application/src/Application/Mvc/Request/HttpRequest.php

```
namespace Application\Mvc\Request;
use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request;

class HttpRequest extends Request
{
    public function hasCookie ($name)
    {
        assert ('is_string($name)');

        $cookie = $this->getCookie();
        if (empty ($cookie))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (isset ($cookie [$name]))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public function cookie ($name, $default = null)
    {
        assert ('is_string($name)');

        if ($this->hasCookie($name))
        {
            $cookie = $this->getCookie();
            return $cookie [$name];
        }

        return $default;
    }
}
```

module/Application/src/Application/Mvc/Response/Factory.php

```
namespace Application\Mvc\Response;

use Zend\Console\Response as ConsoleResponse;
use Zend\Console\Console;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Factory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (Console::isConsole ())
        {
            return new ConsoleResponse ();
        }
        return new HttpResponse ();
    }
}
```

module/Application/src/Application/Mvc/Response/HttpResponse.php

```
namespace Application\Mvc\Response;

use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response;
use Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie;

class HttpResponse extends Response
{
    public function addCookie ($name, $value, $expires = null, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httponly = false, $maxAge = null, $version = null)
    {
        $cookie = new SetCookie ($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly, $maxAge, $version);
        $this->getHeaders ()
            ->addHeader ($cookie);
    }
}
```

Now, I enjoy much easier access to cookies.

```
$this->getRequest ()->cookie ('ptime');
$this->getRequest ()->cookie ('alarm', 'last');
```

and

```
$this->getResponse ()->addCookie ('ptime', time ());
```

Comment: Love easy access to cookies.

Comment: This is same as killing a fly with a cannon. Why not create a controller plugin which would act as a proxy between the controller and the request?

Comment: It could work unless you have the cookie setting logic elsewhere (not in the controller).