# ZF2 - Set cookie in dispatch listener

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

I would like to set a cookie in a listener, if the query parameter "source" is set. I tried the following but the cookie does not exist.

How can I set the cookie correct?

```
class DispatchListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate {

    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $eventManager) {
        $this->listeners[] = $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach(
            'Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface',
            MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, 
            array($this, 'setCookie'), 
            -80
        );
    }

    /**
     * @var \Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param \Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function setCookie(EventInterface $event) {
        if ($source = $this->request->getQuery('source')) {
            $this->request->setCookies([
                'source' => $source
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

--------------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------------

```
class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface, BootstrapListenerInterface {

    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event) {
        $target = $event->getTarget();
        $serviceManager = $target->getServiceManager();
        $eventManager = $target->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach($serviceManager->get('Application\Listener\Dispatch'));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a cookie in your request object or do you want to create a cookie for the response. You probably want to create a cookie and set it on the response object.
Check for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807548/1697459).

```
public function setCookie(EventInterface $event) {
    if ($source = $this->request->getQuery('source')) {
        $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('source', $source);
        $headers = $this->getResponse()->getHeaders();
        $headers->addHeader($cookie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are a few issues with your code, which we can rule out first.

- You haven't provided code for how you are attaching your listener
- Not sure why you are setting the cookie on the request, do you want to do this on the response?

Attaching the event listener:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
  $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
  $app  = $e->getApplication();
  $em = $app->getEventManager();

  // Attach event to attach listener after routing when query will be populated
  $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($eventManager) {
    $request = $e->getRequest();
    // attach our listener 
    $eventManager->attach(new DispatchListener($request));
  });
}
```

Updated setCookie method:

```
public function setCookie(EventInterface $event) { 
    if ($source = $this->request->getQuery('source')) {
        $this->request->setCookies([
            'source' => $source
        ]);

        $request = $this->request;
        $cookieData = $request->getCookie('someCookie', 'default');
        var_dump($cookieData);
    }
}
```

The var_dump prints the following:

```
object(Zend\Http\Header\Cookie)[274]
  protected 'encodeValue' => boolean true
  private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
    array (size=1)
   'source' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: I added the source code where I attach the listener in my Module.php. If I try your code, I won't get the same result as you. The cookie isn't set in my case. I just wan't to set that cookie, if someone calls the website with the `source` query parameter :)

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you are trying to achieve but my method works. Now I guess I would need to see your factory or setter code for Application\Listener\Dispatch in service locator to understand. But if you are passing in the correct request object and the event fires after route event then it should work. But still not sure why you want to set the cookie on the request