# Set cookie in Php Zend framework

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework3

Trying to set cookie in ZF3 project. Found this helpful code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264267/1249426

```
 $cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie('uniqueID', $uniqueID, time()+(86400 * 30));
$this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
```

Now this only work when there is an error on the page (after cookie code), otherwise it does not work. So i'm guessing that there is an issue with the headers reaching the browser correctly. When there is am error php directly sends to the browser and that could be setting the headers right. 
Please advice.